# When I use the constructor signature and the call signature interface, their return value types are not compatible

Tags: typescript

I'm a TypeScript novice, I don't understand why the following code reports a type error, where did I write it wrong?

```js
interface CallOrConstruct {
  new (value: string): Person
  (value: number): number
}

class Person {}

/**
 * TS2322: Type '(value: string | number) => number | Person' is not assignable to type 'CallOrConstruct'.
 * Type 'number | Person' is not assignable to type 'number'.
 * Type 'Person' is not assignable to type 'number'.
 */
const User: CallOrConstruct = function (value: string | number): Person | number {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return new Person()
  } else {
    return value * 2
  }
}
```

The User variable is marked red at the bottom of the editor。

Thank you for your answer, thank you very much.

There is no type error, and the value can be returned normally in the function

Comment: 2 issues: • function expressions aren't treated as overloads as per [ms/TS#47669](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669) so the compiler complains because it doesn't know that `Person | number` will be `Person` and `number` in the right circumstances; • TS doesn't want you to call regular functions with `new` as per [ms/TS#2310](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310).  If you want to do this anyway you can use a type assertion as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/Wvq3rm). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

First, the TypeScript compiler doesn't want to allow you use [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) to construct an object from a function that isn't [explicitly a `class` constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html), at least in TypeScript `.ts` files (it's [different](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#constructor-functions-are-equivalent-to-classes) for using TypeScript to check `.js` files).  There is some amount of support for calling a `void`-returning function statement like a constructor, but [according to a comment in microsoft/TypeScript#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310#issuecomment-168849651) such export will not be expanded and the practice isn't encouraged.  So in order to treat a regular function like a constructor, you will need to use something like [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to work around it.

Second, even if you were using two call signatures like an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), TypeScript can't verify that [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) are assignable, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669) (that issue talks about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but the same limitation is there for `function` expressions).  It sees a function that accepts `string | number` and returns `Person | number` but it cannot verify that a `Person` comes out when a `string` goes in and a `number` comes out when a `number` goes in.  It doesn't try to inspect the control flow inside the function implementation; it just looks at the call signature. For [`function` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) overloads are checked *loosely* and can accept things that are improperly implemented. But for `function` expressions, overloads are checked *strictly* and can reject things that are properly implemented.  In order to treat a function expression like an overload, you will need something like a type assertion.

Since the compiler can't verify your logic for either issue, and since both issues can be worked around with a type assertion, my suggestion is to use such an assertion as follows:

```
const User = function (value: string | number): Person | number {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return new Person()
  } else {
    return value * 2
  }
} as CallOrConstruct;
```

and just double check that you've done so correctly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYYPJVQexAGcwoBXBMZAbwFgAoZZECAdwAoA3TMiALmQkooAOYBKAQAVoRQgyZce-ZmQC2AI2gSVG6AwC+DBggxwiRZNKiyQNZIfrHCJZAFUi0ZAF5kMMiEpgQmRFDF4BIVFkAB8dTShtKxsYuM86RmRgGBCwAE8ABwh8bO4wlC8K5ABySJARKrEaeSZkKAgwMihbFlZLGUJ2MWb9ZAgMDyaMpjaOruRS3mQAKmQAJmGDZDM0TBw8Z1IKMABuI3ogA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your serious and detailed answer, it is very helpful to me, thank you.